# Add Windows 7 to boot menu

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS   - system restore
/dev/sda2              13        4674    37436416    7  HPFS/NTFS  - Windows 7
/dev/sda3            4674       58843   435116032    7  HPFS/NTFS -  data storage
/dev/sda4           58843       60802    15728640   83  Linux - Ubuntu 10.10
```

Initially I installed StartUpManager. This ( I think ) added another 4 instances of Linux + memtest to my boot menu list. However, I did not see the GRUB boot menu. The computer  boots into Ubuntu after a few seconds.

I have tried to add windows 7, but I did not succeed.

This is a part of  my menu.lst file.

```
title        Ubuntu 10.10, kernel 2.6.35-24-generic
uuid        1c9748e2-2f11-4a6c-91c0-7310d48c4a7a
kernel        /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-24-generic root=UUID=1c9748e2-2f11-4a6c-91c0-7310d48c4a7a ro quiet splash
initrd        /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-24-generic


title        Chainload into GRUB 2
root        1c9748e2-2f11-4a6c-91c0-7310d48c4a7a
kernel        /boot/grub/core.img

title        Ubuntu 10.10, memtest86+
uuid        1c9748e2-2f11-4a6c-91c0-7310d48c4a7a
kernel        /boot/memtest86+.bin


menuentry “Windows 7″ {
set root=(hd0,2)
chainloader +1
}
```

And this is after `upgrade-grub`

```
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-24-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
Found GRUB 2: /boot/grub/core.img
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

---

**Later Edit:**

I have added the following to  `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and I have uncommented the hidden menu line from menu.lst, but I still cant see any boot menu.
I have also tried to press ESC and SHIFT.

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" {
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ntfs
  set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
  chainloader +1
}

menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" {
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ntfs
  set root='(hd0,msdos0)'
  chainloader +1    
}

menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" {
  set root= hd(0,0)
  chainloader +1
}

menuentry "!Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" {
  set root= hd(0,1)
  chainloader +1
}

menuentry "!!Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" {    
  set root= hd(0,2)
  chainloader +1
}
```

Comment: Just try `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 8):

This is My windows 7 loader:

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
chainloader +1
}
```

This should work If you copy and paste it, but I dont think you should put it in your menu.lst file. **It should go in /etc/grub.d/40_custom**

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to know your Windows 7 parition. (for me "hd0, msdos2")..
You can use;

```
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os
$menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-9A4600EC4600CB49' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  9A4600EC4600CB49
      else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9A4600EC4600CB49
      fi
      ntldr ($root)/bootmgr # <--- change this
}
```

Or You can use;

```
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader1) (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os
$menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-9A4600EC4600CB49' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  9A4600EC4600CB49
      else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9A4600EC4600CB49
      fi
      ntldr /bootmgr  # <--- change this
}
```

Or you have to open bash..

```
sudo update-grub2

vi grub.cfg
```

** change the lines I have marked with ** # <--- change this** in your grub.cfg.
and then..

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

that's it..