# How do I recover Windows 7 on my Grub menu, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-7

I duel boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 (Windows being installed first) and a couple days ago I jumped on to Ubuntu to check for updates and after it updated, I found that the Windows option had disappeared from the Grub menu.

I have been searching around for way to fix this problem, but none of them seem to work.

I have tried

> sudo update-grub

and get this

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic  
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic     
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-26-generic     
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf     
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin     
done
```

It doesn't have windows in the line up, but when I do

```
fgrep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I get

```
if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then     
menuentry_id_option="--id"    
menuentry_id_option=""     
export menuentry_id_option     
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os     
$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-6094ed1b-2cb2-4c43-b57c-2809c008ed9c' {     
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-6094ed1b-2cb2-4c43-b57c-2809c008ed9c' {     
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-37-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-37-generic-advanced-6094ed1b-2cb2-4c43-b57c-2809c008ed9c' {     
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-37-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-37-generic-recovery-6094ed1b-2cb2-4c43-b57c-2809c008ed9c' {     
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-35-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-35-generic-advanced-6094ed1b-2cb2-4c43-b57c-2809c008ed9c' {     
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-35-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-35-generic-recovery-6094ed1b-2cb2-4c43-b57c-2809c008ed9c' {     
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-26-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-26-generic-advanced-6094ed1b-2cb2-4c43-b57c-2809c008ed9c' {     
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-26-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-26-generic-recovery-6094ed1b-2cb2-4c43-b57c-2809c008ed9c' {     
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {     
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {     
menuentry 'Windows 7' {
```

I see that Windows 7 is there, but it seems like there should be more after it's name, like a location.

I've even tried Boot-repair, but when I run it, it only has one button that saves a log of my boot stuff to a link (http://paste.ubuntu.com/8580395/)

I moved the Windows 7 boot to the top of the Grub menu with "Grub Customizer" and when I went to my Grub menu Windows 7 was there, but when I clicked it is read "Error: No Such Partition"

I'm not that versed in really technical computer stuff, but I know enough to follow your directions. I hope someone can provide a answer that fixes my issue, and that I have provided enough information.

Comment: Based on your boot info summary, it looks like your Windows 7 partition may be on `/dev/sda2` if so running the command `sudo os-prober` should result in output like /dev/sda2:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain

Comment: Related: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/22629/add-windows-7-to-boot-menu?rq=1

Comment: "sudo os-prober" 

It didn't show anything.
>$ sudo os-prober
$

Comment: It looks like the boot flag is missing from your NTFS partition on /dev/sda2. Can you confirm your Windows installation is there if you mount it with Disks

Comment: Should be, that's the partition I made for windows, so yeah.

Comment: If your Windows bootrec is still in place you may be able to resolve the problem by toggling the boot flag back on using gparted and then repeating the `sudo update-grub`... back later

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest release of the boot-repair cd [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) and burn it to disk, boot off of it and then follow the instructions [here.](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)

Recommended Repair will usually do the trick. I've rarely had to use the advanced options.

Further information is available on this [page.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)