# How do I add windows 7 on a new hard drive to grub

Tags: dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on an SSS running perfectly. Got a new 2TB drive that has Windows 7 installed on it.

How do I add Windows 7 to my grub menu?

This is output of `sudo update-grub`:

```
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... 
found: /boot/grub Searching for default file ... 
found: /boot/grub/default Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... 
found: /boot/grub/menu.lst Searching for splash image ... 
none found, skipping ... 
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-51-generic 
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic 
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

This is the output of `sudo os-prober`:

```
sudo os-prober /dev/sdc1:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain
```

Comment: you will need a **new** product key if the mobo is not the one originally registered to windows 7 unless w7 was purchased separately and then in some cases it may be licensed to more than one computer.

Comment: "can I not just manually tell it to add windows?" answered here: http://askubuntu.com/a/22632/40581

Comment: Is `/dev/sdc1` in the `/etc/fstab` ? If not, add it, but with a `noauto` flag.

Comment: @mchid How is that in any way related to the OPs question? Even an unactivated Windows can be booted.

Comment: @the_Seppi While it is in no way an answer or a solution to the question, it is closely related. Microsoft defines "new computer" as a different mobo in the licensing agreement.

Answer (score 2):

Run the command `sudo update-grub`.

If it still does not work try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It will attempt to fix the problem, if it can't it will provide a link with all the information we need to further troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: did that. still nothing.

Comment: Make sure os-prober is installed with `sudo apt-get install os-prober`.

Comment: said that the latest version of os-prober already installed.

Comment: can I not just manually tell it to add windows?

Comment: That is what update-grub does. Can you edit your question with the output of `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: this is output of sudo update-grub: Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-51-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

Comment: this is output of sudo os-prober: sudo os-prober
/dev/sdc1:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain

Comment: You should edit that in you question please, not post it as a comment.

Comment: @Pabi he's edited it in.

Comment: @DarbyGallagher I believe this can happen when windows is not shut down properly. You can run Gparted to find out. Open gparted and select the device /dev/sdc1 and see what is says. If there is an exclamation icon to indicate an error, click on  it to receive relevant information.

Comment: I persume it was never booted, as it is a new drive and not in GRUB.

Comment: @Pabi you can buy a new hard drive with windows already installed?

Comment: Thats what he stated in his question...

Comment: It has never been booted. I ran gparted. I didn't see and exlamation icon. I thought it would be as simple as editing the grub file and simply telling it where to look. I keep trying to have a linux installation but have to give up because I can't get something to work. I believe in linux, but it just doesn't want to work for me.

Comment: @DarbyGallagher I believe your issue is getting windows to work and not linux. have you tried to run sudo update grub again or did you just run it once and  give up?

Comment: As stated in my answer, please try boot-repair. It may be able solve the problem, if not will provide the information we need.

Comment: @DarbyGallagher as a test, disconnect the Ubuntu drive and only have the windows drive connected. Boot up the computer and see why windows isn't working. I suspect your problem is there if update grub does not work

Comment: I have run sudo update grub numerous times. I have the most perfect install of Linux I have ever had since I started with it with Red Hat 2.0. The problem is, if I can't have windows running for my kids, it doesn't matter how great linux is for me.

Comment: I will try rebooting without linux drive attached before I wipe the linux drive.

Comment: I do not talk about `update-grub`. I am talking about boot-repair which is linked in my answer.

Comment: @Pabi address your comment with @ + DarbyGallagher at the beginning so that he will receive a notification for it.

Comment: No boot-repair in ubuntu software, and I won't remember the commands if I boot from live-cd. Says no match for boot-repair.

Comment: If you follow the link and read the few lines there is all the informations you need on how to install or run it from a live media.

Comment: He will get the notification anyway because it is his question.